# converting colored Image to an Array[i][j]

Tags: java, image, matlab, image-processing, cross-correlation

I would like to compute the Normalized Cross Correlation between two images using Java.

My program works fine but when I tried to verify my results in MATLAB, I unfortunately did not get the same results as I did with my Java implementation.

This is the code that I performed in MATLAB:

```
Img1 = rgb2gray(imread('image1.png'));
Img2 = rgb2gray(imread('image2.png'));
corr2(Img1, Img2);
```

This is part of my Java implementation.  Some of the classes have been removed for better understanding:

I am not sure what is wrong with my Java implementation.

I also have one other question.  In MATLAB, I had to convert the image to grayscale before using `corr2`.  Do I need to do the same in Java?

Comment: You really need to add your Java code and your Matlab code to your question. Please edit your question and add this information (don't add it in comments or links)

Comment: Is it more clear now ?

Comment: @user3475463: If you are computing the corrolation once on an RGB and once on an grayscale image, you can not expect the same output. Your code seems to be incomplete, I can't find a definition of `computeCorrelationCoefficient`

Comment: Oh sorry I've made a mistake.. ComputeCorrelationCoefficient and ComputeCorrelation are the same and CorrelationUtils is the java class with the method ComputeCorrelation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it isn't the same is because you didn't account for the headers in the PNG file.

If you take a look at your Java code, you are reading in the image as a byte stream in your `readImage` method. For PNG, there are headers involved such as the size of the image and how many bits of colour per pixel there are.  Not only are you grabbing image data (which by the way is compressed using a version of LZW so you're not even reading in raw image data), but you are also grabbing in extra information which is being collected in your correlation code.

What's confusing is that you are reading in the image fine using the `BufferedImage` type at the beginning of your correlation code to obtain the rows and columns.  Why did you switch to using a byte stream in your `readImage` method?

As such, you need to change your `readImage` method to take in the `BufferedImage` object, or reread the data like you did in the correlation method in your `readImage` method.  Once you do that, use the `BufferedImage` methods to access the RGB pixels.  FWIW, if you are reading in the image as grayscale, then every channel should give you the same intensity so you can operate on one channel alone.  Doesn't matter which.... but make sure that you're doing correlation on grayscale images.  It is ambiguous when you go to colour, as there is currently no set standard on how to do this.

Using `BufferedImage`, you can use the `getRGB` method to obtain the pixel you want at column `x` and row `y`.  `x` traverses from left to right, while `y` traverses from top to bottom.  When you call `getRGB` it returns a single 32-bit integer in ARGB format.  Each channel is 8 bits.  As such, the first 8 bits (MSB) are the alpha value, the second 8 bits are for red, the third 8 bits are for green, and the final 8 are for blue.  Depending on what channel you want, you need to bitshift and mask out the bits you don't need to get the value you want.

As an example:

```
int rgb = img.getRGB(x, y);
int alpha = rgb >> 24 & 0xFF;
int red = rgb >> 16 & 0xFF;
int green = rgb >> 8 & 0xFF;
int blue = rgb & 0xFF;
```

For the alpha value, you need to shift to the right by 24 bits to get it down to the LSB positions, then mask with `0xFF` to obtain only the 8 bits that represent the alpha value.  Similarly you would have do the same for the red, green and blue channels.  Because correlation is rather ill-posed for colour images, let's convert the image to grayscale within your `readImage` method.  As such, there is no need to convert the image before you run this method.  We will do that within the method itself to save you some hassle.

If you take a look at how MATLAB performs `rgb2gray`, it performs a weighted sum, weighting the channels differently.  The weights are defined by the [SMPTE Rec. 601 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_%28video%29#Rec._601_luma_versus_Rec._709_luma_coefficients) (for those of you that want to figure out how I know this, you can take a look at the source of `rgb2gray` and read off the first row of their transformation matrix.  These coefficients are essentially the definition of the 601 standard).

Previous versions of MATLAB simply added up all of the channels, divided by 3 and took the floor.  I don't know which version of MATLAB you are using, but to be safe I'm going to use the most up to date conversion.

```
public static void readImage(BufferedImage img, int array[][], int nrows, int ncols) {
      for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
           for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {
                int rgb = img.getRGB(j, i);
                int red = rgb >> 16 & 0xFF;
                int green = rgb >> 8 & 0xFF;
                int blue = rgb & 0xFF;
                array[i][j] = (int) (0.299*((double)red) + 0.587*((double)green) + 
                               0.114*((double)blue) );
           }
}
```

This should hopefully give you what you want!

Comment: First thank you for your answer :) So now I should convert my images to grayscale, then change my readImage method with BufferedImage object.. should I change something in my compute correlation method? and if I will work with grayscale images it won't be necessary to use getRGB in order to access the pixels  ?

Comment: You're very welcome. You don't need to change anything in your correlation method provided that you read in the pixels properly. You will need to use getRGB to access the pixel data as this is the only way to obtain the image data for your image. You **will** need to mask out which channel you want from the pixel data though.  I'll edit my answer to show you.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D while I was waiting I wrote this code http://pastebin.com/cQe8pZQ9  but now I will try your example. What I still don't understant, if I work with one channel will it still be necessary to convert images to grayscale? I feel like this is a stupid question but something is not clear yet to me

Comment: You need to convert the image to grayscale first **BEFORE** you read it into `BufferedImage`.  If you don't, then there will be different intensities for each channel.  Each channel gives you the "strength" of the colour for that channel.  You don't have to do this and you can convert within Java itself.  What I will do is edit my code so that we're assuming the input is colour, and I will convert the image to grayscale for you.

Comment: So I guess it's done :) I can't thank you enough .. I will try it now

Comment: You're very welcome. Also check my edit. MATLAB has changed the way they convert RGB to grayscale by using the SMPTE Rec. 601 standard.  Also, if this answer has helped, please consider accepting it.

Comment: You're very welcome.  I also missed removing the division by 3 from the previous version I had.  Make sure you remove this in your most up to date code.  I also removed it from my post.